# Get elements from tags in xml in java

Tags: java, xml, tags

if i have the following xml :

```
<Shapes>
    <Numbers>n-3</Numbers>
    <Ellipse.0>
        <Color>
            <Red>r-0</Red>
            <Green>g-0</Green>
            <Blue>b-255</Blue>
        </Color>
        <FillColor>
            <Red>r-0</Red>
            <Green>g-0</Green>
            <Blue>b-255</Blue>
        </FillColor>
        <Position>
            <X>x-12</X>
            <Y>y-12</Y>
        </Position>
        <properties>
            <Hight>v-123.0</Hight>
            <Width>v-12.0</Width>
        </properties>
    </Ellipse.0>
</Shapes>
```

and i want code in java that get names of elements of a tag for Example:
elements of the tag properties are (Hight, Width)

this is my method :

```
public static List<String> getNodes(String fileName, String nodeName) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{   

    try {
        List<String> nodes = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Create a factory
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory =    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        // Use the factory to create a builder
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(fileName);

        NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName(nodeName);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            // Get element
            Element element = (Element) list.item(i);
            nodes.add(element.getNodeName());

        }
        return nodes;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

if the nodeName = "Properties" it returns list that contain["Properties","Properties","Properties"]

Comment: Try posting what you've tried.

Comment: What xml parser are you using?  What problems are you having with your current implementation?

Comment: @km1 i edited the post

Comment: @azurefrog   i edited the post

Comment: that's correct so far. Properties is one node, the two child nodes the others... now work with that..

Answer (score -1):

Once you've found a `<properties>` node you want to extract the names of its child nodes. This works for me:

```java
List<String> nodes = new ArrayList<String>();
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
        .newDocumentBuilder()
        .parse(fileName);
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName(nodeName);  // find <properties> node(s)
NodeList childList = list.item(0).getChildNodes();  // list.item(0) is first (and only) match
for (int i = 0; i < childList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node childNode = childList.item(i);
    String childNodeName = childNode.getNodeName();
    if (!childNodeName.equals("#text")) {
        nodes.add(childNodeName);
    }
}
```

Comment: And how does it work? What did OP learn from this? Why would he invest time for the next problem instead of simply coming back here to have someone do the work for them again?